# Syntax errors, unexpected end of file no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou recebendo este erro em meu código ao final do arquivo, não consegui encontrar o erro no código:

Syntax errors, unexpected end of file.

Aqui está o meu código do arquivo web.php que está dando o erro:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\controllers\admin\AuthAdminController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

// Route::get('url', [Controller::class, 'classe']);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

/**
 * Admin
 */

 Route::group(['middleware' => ['authAdmin']], function () {
     Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
         Route::get('/', [AuthAdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin');
});

Route::get('/admin/login', function(){
    return view('admin/login');
})->name('admin.login');

/**
 * Fim Admin
 */
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tente adicionar }); abaixo da linha Route::get('/', [AuthAdminController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('admin');